# Auto Delete or Close Low Quality Post

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Wouldn't it be nice if there is some feature or automatic system that will delete all the questions and answers that has down votes more than a threshold value(say 10 or 5 after a week or so of posting) which would keep the site clean and take off all the low quality posts and also would give the moderators a breather.

Comment: We already have several processes to delete posts under certain criteria. Just number of downvotes is much too general and not useful.

Comment: I've found that sometimes low quality posts that I find via search engine link me to a better quality question though.

Comment: Reduce the load on the moderators? Pffft. You can't even *imagine* how many "Why was my perfectly good question deleted?" questions we'd get on Meta. Anyway, what's wrong with just leaving the question closed? Why do we need to delete it?

Comment: @BLaZuRE But wouldn't it be nice if it directed you to the better quality post from search page?

Comment: @Oded I agree on that but sometimes i see questions with as many as 20 downvotes on SO. You might be right about posts with downvotes less than 5 or 10

Comment: @Rohit True, but sometimes they have the same syntax and are a more relevant match then mine.  Besides, based on the pagination on Stack Overflow, questions less than -4 are less than 1%

Comment: @CodyGray Every closed question stays on the SO for a while. And it provides enough reasons (in comments) for why it was closed/deleted.

Comment: So? Why not leave them there? Moderators don't go looking for those - only if they get flagged will they get noticed.

Comment: "take off all the low quality posts" You forgot about the ones that get hundreds of upvotes.

Comment: You mean, like, [deleting unanswered negative-scored answers after some set amount of days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/21960)?